# Eclipse Che 7 Node.js Error: This workspace is using old definition format

Tags: node.js, eclipse-che

I am new to using Eclipse Che. After trying (and failing, see error at the end) to install it on a local kubernetes cluster according to this [article](https://che.eclipse.org/running-eclipse-che-on-kubernetes-using-docker-desktop-for-mac-5d972ed511e1), I ended up running it locally using docker according to documentation on: https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-6/docker-single-user.html. Even thought this is the documentation for version 6 it seems to start version 7 just fine.

It starts up normally (warnings don't matter AFAIK):

```
WARN: Bound 'eclipse/che' to 'eclipse/che:7.0.0-beta-5.0'
INFO: Proxy: HTTP_PROXY=gateway.docker.internal:3128, HTTPS_PROXY=gateway.docker.internal:3129, NO_PROXY=
WARN: Potential networking issue discovered!
WARN: We have identified that http and https proxies are set but no_proxy is not. This may cause fatal networking errors. Set no_proxy for your Docker daemon!
INFO: (che cli): 7.0.0-beta-5.0 - using docker 18.06.1-ce / docker4mac
WARN: Newer version 'rc' available
INFO: (che init): Installing configuration and bootstrap variables:
INFO: (che init):   CHE_HOST=192.168.65.3
INFO: (che init):   CHE_VERSION=7.0.0-beta-5.0
INFO: (che init):   CHE_CONFIG=~/che
INFO: (che init):   CHE_INSTANCE=~/che/instance
INFO: (che config): Generating che configuration...
INFO: (che config): Customizing docker-compose for running in a container
INFO: (che start): Preflight checks
         mem (1.5 GiB):           [OK]
         disk (100 MB):           [OK]
         port 8080 (http):        [AVAILABLE]
         conn (browser => ws):    [OK]
         conn (server => ws):     [OK]

INFO: (che start): Starting containers...
INFO: (che start): Services booting...
INFO: (che start): Server logs at "docker logs -f che"
INFO: (che start): Booted and reachable
INFO: (che start): Ver: 7.0.0-beta-5.0
INFO: (che start): Use: http://localhost:8080
INFO: (che start): API: http://localhost:8080/swagger
```

I get the workspace set up screen and select the *node.js* stack. The stack is created just fine and the workspace is running. However, then, I am stuck. Cannot create any new project or import project. If I go to the workspace configuration, the top bar shows the following error:

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse Che in browser showing top bar with error message: "This workspace is using old definition format which is not compatible anymore"]

The IDE shows "There are no projects", even though they are shown when listing projects from the workspace overview:

[image: Eclipse Che Project list showing "There are no projects"]

[image: Eclipse Che Workspace > Projects view showing two created projects]

I tried looking in the documentation, but since the link points to the docs for version 6, it does not mention anything about updating the workspace definition. I also tried deleting and re-creating the workspace and I tried creating a project from a template (`nodejs-hello-world` and `web-nodejs-simple`).

Is there anyone who has the same problem or has already solved it? There should be a way to use old workspace definitions. I guess my next step is to downgrade to version 6 or to follow the installation steps for version 7, which is using `chectl`.

PS: for completeness sake, here is the error I ran into when following the manual on installing eclipse che 6 using docker for Mac:

```
helm upgrade --install che --namespace che --set cheImage=eclipse/che-server:6.19.5 --set global.cheWorkspacesNamespace="che" --set 
global.ingressDomain=${CHE_DOMAIN}.nip.io ./
Release "che" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: validation failed: error validating "": error validating data: 
[unknown object type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.CHE_LOGGER_CONFIG, unknown 
object type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.CHE_OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENTID, unknown object 
type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.CHE_OAUTH_GITHUB_CLIENTSECRET, unknown object 
type "nil" in ConfigMap.data.CHE_WORKSPACE_HTTPS__PROXY, unknown object type 
"nil" in ConfigMap.data.CHE_WORKSPACE_HTTP__PROXY, unknown object type "nil" 
in ConfigMap.data.CHE_WORKSPACE_NO__PROXY]
```

UPDATE 1: Added screenshots of projects and project view. Also tried downgrading to 6.19.0, with same result. Of course I also checked the documentation for Che 7, but it also does not mention updating workspace definitions.

UPDATE 2: Using `chectl` according to the [quick-starts guide](https://www.eclipse.org/che/docs/che-7/che-quick-starts.html) did not help, since I ran into an issue when starting up the pods. I reported the [issue](https://github.com/che-incubator/chectl/issues/124) to the chectl team and hope to be able to help them resolve it.